Choose meal based on list of requirements
I wrote code in Prolog for an exam and was told that the following part of the code is not "standard" Prolog.
This is the feedback my professor gave me: The check_preferences rule is not standard Prolog.
How can it be improved? I'm not sure why it's not standard Prolog.
check_preferences(Meal, Preferences) :- 
    (member(lactose_free, Preferences) -> meal_lactose_free(Meal) ; true), 
    (member(gluten_free, Preferences) -> meal_gluten_free(Meal) ; true), 
    (member(vegetarian, Preferences) -> meal_vegetarian(Meal) ; true).

Is this better or worse:
check_preferences(Meal, Preferences) :-    
    ( member(lactose_free, Preferences), meal_lactose_free(Meal) ; \+ member(lactose_free, Preferences) ),
    ( member(gluten_free, Preferences), meal_gluten_free(Meal) ; \+ member(gluten_free, Preferences) ),
    ( member(vegetarian, Preferences), meal_vegetarian(Meal) ; \+ member(vegetarian, Preferences) ).


Code reviews should be posted on [codereview.se].

3 lines of code is not a code review. It's a "show me how to think in Prolog" steer.

@Cow, the question needs work before it's suited to [codereview.se]. You could have pointed the asker at A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users, as some things are done differently over there - e.g. we need a good description of the purpose of the code to give context, and question titles should simply say what the code is for (the question is always, "How can I improve this?").  It's important that the code works correctly; include the unit tests if possible.

This question is unclear and opinion-based as phrased. What kind of improvement are you looking for? Why do you think the second code block would be any different? It sounds like you should ask the person who told you it isn't "standard" what they mean by that.

I have voted to reopen. "Opinion-based" is nonsense. Could post on https://www.reddit.com/r/prolog/ instead.

I think you have to start by explaining what non-standard Prolog means. In what way is the second code meant to be better or worse? What are your criteria to judge this?

@brebs For one, Dharman, being a moderator effectively is the SO police. If someone votes to close, it goes into the close review, and if someone votes to reopen a question, it gets into the reopen queue, which means users actively reviewing will see the question. Also, determining if something is insufficiently explained or asking for opinions does not need in-depth knowledge of a specific language.

a. it is not non-standard Prolog. b. the second snippet is worse, being less standard and less efficient, calculating the member second time needlessly for each of the checks.

@TylerH this question is perfectly clear for a Prolog coder. I'm guessing you're not (after a cursory look at your profile's top tags). Cheers.

@MarkRotteveel "determining if something is insufficiently explained or asking for opinions does not need in-depth knowledge of a specific language." wrong. the evidence to that is all around in the above comments.

@WillNess Then you need to edit the question to make clear to everyone. Does the term "better" mean one objective thing to everyone in Prolog? If so, that's rather surprising and amazing, as no other language on the planet has achieved that. More likely, this is simply a case, like in some other programming language communities here, where users of that language often agree on opinion-based things to the point where they expect those opinions to be considered "standard" or "idiomatic" without any actual authority or specification that says so.

Some key critical information is missing.

Is a caller providing arguments?
Is {lactose_free, gluten_free, vegetarian} mutually exclusive?

Your code seems assuming that.


I imagine some "facts" have been provided to use.

For example, was meal_lactose_free provided or did you create it?



Without this information, there could be only limited suggestions such as restructuring/reorganizing the same code.
If I have written everything from the scratch, I would have just made the following fact tables and build relations around it.
For example,
% Lactose-free meals
preference_food(lactose_free, curry).

% Gluten-free meals
preference_food(gluten_free, rice).

% Vegetarian meals
preference_food(vegetarian, soup).

% Lactose-free and gluten-free only
preference_food(lactose_free, sushi_roll).
preference_food(gluten_free, sushi_roll).

% Gluten-free and vegetarian only
preference_food(gluten_free, tofu_stir_fry).
preference_food(vegetarian, tofu_stir_fry).

% Lactose-free and vegetarian only
preference_food(lactose_free, veggie_curry).
preference_food(vegetarian, veggie_curry).

% Lactose-free, gluten-free, and vegetarian
preference_food(lactose_free, quinoa_bowl).
preference_food(gluten_free, quinoa_bowl).
preference_food(vegetarian, quinoa_bowl).

%% preference_foods(+Preference:atom, -Foods:list(atom))
%
% Find all `Foods` associated with a given `Preference`.
preference_foods(Preference, Foods) :-
    setof(Food, preference_food(Preference, Food), Foods).

%% preferences_food(+Preferences:list(atom), -Food:atom)
%
% Find all `Food` with a given `Preferences`.
preferences_food(Preferences, Food) :-
    setof(Food, preference_food(Preferences, Food), Food).

%% preferences_foods(+Preferences:list(atom), -Foods:list(atom))
%
% Find all `Foods` with given `Preferences`.
preferences_foods(Preferences, Foods) :-
    maplist(preference_foods, Preferences, FoodsSets),
    ord_intersection(FoodsSets, Foods).


Consider [lactose_free,gluten_free,vegetarian] that is, all three requirements must hold,  whereas you require only one of them to be ensured.
